# How to crop the live video based on the condition in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, video-streaming, video-processing

Just imagine you are getting two inputs from two different system. System 'A' gives unique ID and system 'B' gives you live streaming video. I have to crop the video based on changes in the unique ID from system 'A' and save it as the name of uniqueId.mp4

Let, say **example** I'm getting unique ID as 6789 for 10 minutes from system A and the unique ID suddenly changed to 6790  we have to store the 10 minutes video in the name of unique ID (i.e.) 6789.mp4. Like wise, we have to store N number of videos based on the unique ID changes.

Can you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...!

If value changes in the text file, I will crop and save in the name of uniqueId.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    currentUniqueId = file.readline()
temp = currentUniqueId

for i in range(1, 3):
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(str(currentUniqueId)+'.mp4v', fourcc, 20, (frame_width,frame_height),True)
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
            with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
                currentUniqueId = file.readline()
            if currentUniqueId != temp:
                print(str(temp)+'.mp4v file created')
                temp = currentUniqueId
                break
        else:
            break
    out.release()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```